# iOS 8 Keyboard Extension Buttons Not Showing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, xcode6

I have added the keyboard extension target to my iOS 8 app but the buttons are not appearing on my iPhone 5s. I have run the app and keyboard on the simulator and an iPod touch (all running iOS 8) and they work. It is only the phone that does not. I am using Xcode 6 beta and writing in Swift.
It is only the code that is automatically generated when adding the extension.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. It shows for an simulated iPad but not for an simulated iPhone. I am quite sure that my code is not executed at all. All I get is a "Next Keyboard" button in the left bottom corner.

Comment: Did you deleted the app from the simulator, cleared derived data, cleaned the project and rebuilt it?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to Xcode 6.0.1 Not the beta. Got released a few days ago from the app store.

Comment: As silly as it is, but yes, this helped. I can't believe that I spent months trying to find this configuration between iPad and iPhone keyboards. And now it's fixed with another release...

Comment: Glad it worked. Xcode 6.0.1 is a much more stable release. It would be greatly appreciated if you could tick this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: This isn't my question. Nothing to tick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Close all text editing apps before checking keyboard extension on device.